# Throwing a logical error exception or just abort in a library?

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, assert

I like very much the assert behaviour for testing invariants and pre-conditions in my code. I use it a lot. But now I am developing a library (C++) and I like the client (the programmer who uses the library) to know when he violates the precondition. I think is easier to see the application crashes and fix the problem than just throwing in a undefined behaviour.

I could just use assert in this situation, but when my library is ready a release build will disable the assert macro. I know I can keep it but I'm not sure I want to because there is a lot of internal asserts don't need being tested in release build.

An instance:
Some state machine has a maximum number of states that can be added. The limit is setted by the client in the constructor. Then, the client calls the method addState to add specific states, but of course, he can't add more states than he said initially.

Should I:

1. Just ignore states after the limit and, probably, start a state machine with undefined behaviour (at least to client perspective)?
2. Keep assertions alive and put an assertion at that point?
3. Throw an exception (some std::logic_error, I presume)?
4. Just print a message to stderr and abort the program?

I don't like 1. very much. The idea is tell the client what is he doing wrong.

Is this a situation to throw a logical error exception?
Is there another, better possibility?

Thanks.

Comment: As the "client" are doing something exceptional, throwing an exception would not be wrong.

Comment: Yes, assertions are not for checking user errors in production code, they're for testing programmer errors in a debug build. An exception is kind of a "clean" and correct solution.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you very much. Is the logic_error a good choice or the domain_error (or another) is better in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, if a problem is "detectable", you should do something to inform the "user" of the error (some things are very hard to identify that it's gone wrong)

You use assert when the programmer does something directly wrong, and that is unlikely to happen in "normal use" of the code. E.g. if you have a pointer parameter that mustn't be NULL, doing `assert(ptr != NULL)` would be a sensible thing, likewise if you have an `int` that is a count of something, it probably shouldn't be negative (but then it should probably be `unsigned`?). These type of things don't necessarily need to be that clearly documented - just that the precondition "`ptr` must not be NULL" or "`count` should not be negative".

You use exceptions for something that MAY happen in normal running conditions, but really shouldn't. Such as running out of memory, or the "user" trying to add too many things to something that they had a reason to give a reasonable size in the first place. Exceptions should be clearly documented by the description of the function - "If you try to add more states than you have reserved space for, the exception x will be thrown".

I personally would think that a "custom" exception would make more sense than `std::logic_error`. In this case, perhaps `too_many_states`? The more distinct your exception is, the easier it is to determine where it came from and what it means. Nothing worse than getting some "generic" exception and not knowing how you ended up there - and when you search for it, there are hundreds of places it could have come from...

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it is very clear for my now. I will use custom exceptions in this situation and keep assertions internally.